# Wordpress. Multiple subdomains, same theme. How to do it?

Tags: wordpress, themes, subdomain

I have a theme that I want to use on several subdomains and I am wondering what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: do you have dedicated server or do you want to do this on shared hosting?

Comment: @samiulAminShanto I have shared hosting.